# How to filter data on a page based on selection from drop down list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu

I have a Dictionary object that has business type id and list of Questions. I have a drop down of business types. Now when i select a business type from the drop down, i need to refresh the questions list that is shown on the page

html:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="" class="">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select a Business Type *</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="businessTypeSelectionModal">
            <option value="">--Select---</option>
            @foreach (var bt in Model.BusinessTypes)
            {
                <option value="@bt.Id">
                    @bt.Name
                </option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <label>Questions *</label>

</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    var selectedBusinessTypeId;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#businessTypeSelectionModal").change(function () {
            selectedBusinessTypeId = $("#businessTypeSelectionModal").val();
            LoadQuestions(selectedBusinessTypeId);
        });
    });
    function LoadQuestions(selectedBusinessTypeId)
    {
        html = '';
        alert('BT id:' + selectedBusinessTypeId);
     @foreach (var c in Model.Questions)
         {
             foreach (var q in c.Value)
             {
                 if (c.Key == selectedBusinessTypeId) {
                     html += '<label value="@c.Key" class="" />' + @q.Description;
html += '<input type="textbox" />';
                 }
             }
         }

     } 
</script>
```

On selection change of the drop down, i am trying to get the id, pass it to LoadQuestions() function where i need to check if the id is equal to the id in the questions dictionary. If it is i need to show the question as a label and a text box next to each question. As of now i am getting the followin errors:

'selectedBusinessTypeId' & 'html' variables -> inside the LoadQuestions() function does not exist in the current context

Any help would be appreciated. Is there a better way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use JSON serialize your model into a javascript variable and use this javascript variable to write your javascript code :

```
function LoadQuestions(selectedBusinessTypeId)  
{
    html = '';

    var questions = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Questions));
    for (var type in questions) {
        if (type == selectedBusinessTypeId) {

            for (var i = 0; i < questions[type].length; i++) {
                alert( questions[type][i].description)
                //html += "<label value='" + questions[type][i].id + "' class='' />" + questions[type][i].description;
              // html += "<input type='textbox' />";
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Assume type of Model.Questions is :

```
 public Dictionary<int, List<Question>> Questions { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's a great answer @nan Yu.. i have been struggling with this over the past 2 days and it would never have come to my mind to use Json.Serialize .. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

does `$("#businessTypeSelectionModal").val()` contain the value of id or the business type?
You can get id by this
selectedBusinessTypeId= $("#businessTypeSelectionModal").find('option:selected').attr('id');

Comment: Hope this helps. Feel free to ask anything

Comment: $("#businessTypeSelectionModal").val() contains the value.. my problem is in using the 'foreach' loop inside the jQuery function i think.. i dont think this is allowed.. here lies the problem..

Comment: First of all you need to pass the id and not the value as the id has to be compared with that in the dictionary. right now you are passing value, that's why it is comparing value with id and not id with id. Pass the id in the same way as i mentioned above

Comment: Secondly u can append like this var question=@q.Description;         
    $("#labelid").val(question);    replace label id with your actual id of the label

Comment: No @codingsolutions .. lets for a minute forget about the value inside the id property.. the error i am getting is a compilation error which means that the code does not even build and i get the red swiggly below the 'selectedBusinessTypeId' variable..

Comment: i think 'for' needs to be used instead of 'foreach' .. i tried but getting an error at :  for (c in @Model.Questions) line.. 'Unexpected number' -> for (c in System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ServiceTransparencyData.Models.Question]])

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Nan Yu, using Json.Serialize solved the problem